# What's the name of this video door eye wire connector? (port and connector)

Tags: identification, connector, camera, port

I bought a [video eye on Aliexpress.](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32971098255.html?spm=a2g2w.orderdetail.0.0.75574aa65bA1fn&sku_id=12000026415727265) A wire with a connector comes from the peephole, and there is a port on the back of the screen.
What are their names? Is it some kind of USB or what is it?

[image]

UPD: I need to extend the wire.
Therefore, I need to find an extension cable for this connector.
If the extension cable does not exist, I will have to solder.

Comment: mezzanine connector ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mezzanine+connector&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: It's a mezzanine connector, but there are tons of types of those, and they don't correspond to any particular signalling standard. You could probably pin down a specific (or at least compatible) connector if you added some measurements, but to determine how things are communicating over it might be harder, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> port and connector

- Port:

After a bit of research, it appears not to be a port at all (and certainly not USB or any common protocol). It appears to be just an internal connector between the main control PCB and a FPC (Flex Printed Circuit) to a peripheral with a variety of proprietary signal lines.

- Connector:

That is a [3.5 mm, dual beam, mezzanine, board-to-board connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=dual_beam_b2b_conn_0p3) (my site). If you measure the center-to-center distance between the first and the last pin in mm, we can divide it by 14 to calculate the pitch and then narrow it down to the specific part.

It could be:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM15FR) - [BM15FR](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM15FR&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D51095_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/53v7fr0p)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM23FR?lang=en) - [BM23FR](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM23FR&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D162519_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/zd0w8n)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM23PF?lang=en) - [BM23PF](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM23PF&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D165617_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/zd0w8n)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM24) - [BM24](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM24&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D47680_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/05twvch4)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM28?lang=en) - [BM28](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM28&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D143865_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/9z33w4d3)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM29?lang=en) - [BM29](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM29&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D141087_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/4zdv4q7j)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/BM46) - [BM46](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=BM46&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=ed_BM46_CAT) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/5nz5mvm4)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/slimstack_fine_pitch_smt_board_to_board_connectors) - SlimStack 0.35mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/5wh800j4)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/slimstack_fine_pitch_smt_board_to_board_connectors) - SlimStack Armor 0.35mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/frmpr59z)
- [Panasonic](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/connector/base-fpc/a35s/index.jsp?c=search) - A35S - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/4n7wq2rf)
- Panasonic - AF35S - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/919d3pzb)
- Panasonic - AP35S - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/bth70ncr)
- Panasonic - AP35UH - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7qdn7pbr)
- Panasonic - AP35US - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/rphhnjn1)
- [Panasonic](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/connector/base-fpc/r35k/index.jsp?c=search) - R35K - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/2n4zvzfq)
- [Panasonic](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/connector/base-fpc/s35/index.jsp?c=search) - [S35](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/cdn/e/control/connector/base-fpc/catalog/con_eng_s35.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7jbqdm0z)
- [Panasonic](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/dl/cad/index.jsp?series_cd=3577) - S35H - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/p9tdr4jm)

Comment: I measured as you said:


https://ibb.co/hRDy7Yd - connector length;

https://ibb.co/cCLYRYt - connector pins length;

https://ibb.co/VQ8hvp2 - stripped connector wire in front;

https://ibb.co/16CrM3F - stripped connector wire back;

https://ibb.co/4Vp1FB4 - port length;

https://ibb.co/8zC8nT6 - port pins length;

Comment: _port length_. That's not a "port". That's a "connector". Please see my edit in my answer.